# pythonのtkinterを使ったEchoアプリでエラーがでる。（AttributeError 'functors.partial' obj has no attribute '__name__')

Tags: python

"パーフェクトpython"を見て、Echoアプリケーションを作っていましたが、「python3 client.py」と実行すると、以下のエラーが発生します。どういう意味でしょうか？もちろん、server側のプログラムも立ち上げています。
 なお、client側とserver側のコードも示しています。（教材に書いているコードそのままなんですけど。。。）
　解決策も教えていただけませんでしょうか？

【エラー内容】

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "client.py", line 76, in <module>
    main()
  File "client.py", line 68, in main
    root.after(200, functools.partial(idle_task, root))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/tkinter/__init__.py", line 752, in after
    callit.__name__ = func.__name__
AttributeError: 'functools.partial' object has no attribute '__name__'
```

client側コード

```
# -*- coding::utf-8 -*-
import tkinter
import asyncore
import functools
import sys
class EchoView(tkinter.Frame):
    """ Echo User Interface """
    def __init__(self, master):
        super(EchoView, self).__init__(master)
        self.listcontainer = tkinter.Frame(self)
        self.listbox = tkinter.Listbox(self.listcontainer)
        self.yscroll = tkinter.Scrollbar(self.listcontainer)
        self.listbox.pack(side=tkinter.LEFT, expand=True, fill=tkinter.BOTH)
        self.yscroll.pack(side=tkinter.LEFT, expand=True, fill=tkinter.Y)
        self.listcontainer.pack(expand=True, fill=tkinter.BOTH)
        self.entry = tkinter.Entry(self)
        self.entry.pack(side=tkinter.BOTTOM, expand=True, fill=tkinter.X)
    def get_submit_messegae(self):
        data = self.entry.get()
        self.entry.delete(0, tkinter.END)
        return data
    def show_message(self, message):
        self.listbox.insert(tkinter.END, message)
        self.listbox.see(tkinter.END)
class EchoClient(asyncore.dispatcher_with_send):
    def __init__(self, view):
        super(EchoClient, self).__init__()
        self.create_socket()
        self.buffers = []
        self.view = view
        self.bind_all()
    def bind_all(self):
        self.view.entry.bind('<Return>', self.on_submit)
    def on_submit(self, event):
        message = self.view.get_submit_messegae()
        self.buffers.append(message.encode('utf-8'))
    def handle_write(self):
        if not self.buffers:
            return
        buffer, self.buffers = self.buffers[0],self.buffers[1:]
        self.send(buffer)
    def writable(self):
        return self.buffers
    def handle_read(self):
        message = self.recv(8192)
        self.view.show_message(message.decode('utf-8'))
def idle_task(root):
    try:
        asyncore.loop(count=1, timeout=1)
    finally:
        root.after(200, functools.partial(idle_task, root))
def main():
        root = tkinter.Tk()
        root.after(200, functools.partial(idle_task, root))
        view = EchoView(root)
        view.pack(expand=True, fill=tkinter.BOTH)
        client = EchoClient(view)
        client.connect(('localhost', 8080))
        root.mainloop()
if __name__ == '__main__':
        main()
```

server側コード

```
import asyncore
class EchoHandler(asyncore.dispatcher_with_send):
    def __init__(self, socket, parent):
        super(EchoHandler, self).__init__(socket)
        self.parent = parent
    def handle_read(self):
        data = self.recv(8192)
        if data:
            self.parent.send(data)
class EchoServer(asyncore.dispatcher):
    def __init__(self, host, port):
        asyncore.dispatcher.__init__(self)
        self.handlers = []
        self.create_socket()
        self.set_reuse_addr()
        self.bind((host, port))
        self.listen(5)
    def handle_accepted(self, sock, addr):
        print('Incoming connection from %s' % repr(addr))
        handler = EchoHandler(sock)
        self.handlers.append(handler)
    def send(self, data):
        for handler in self.handlers:
            handler.send(data)
server = EchoServer('localhost', 8080)
syncore.loop()
```

※lambda関数を使用した際のエラーメッセージ

> Incoming connection from ('127.0.0.1', 51076)
>       error: uncaptured python exception, closing channel 
>       <**main**.EchoServer listening localhost:8080 at 0x107e18f28> (:**init**() missing 1 required positional argument: 'parent' 
>   [/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/asyncore.py|read|83]
>   [/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/asyncore.p
>   y|handle_read_event|416] 
>   [/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/asyncore.p
>   y|handle_accept|493] [server.py|handle_accepted|27])

Comment: 参考: [tkinter と functools.partial()](http://hokkun-dayo.hatenablog.com/entry/2017/07/18/234939)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

idle_task関数とmain関数の`root.after`から始まる行を下記のように書き換えて動作を確認してみてください。

修正前: `root.after(200, functools.partial(idle_task, root))`
修正後: `root.after(200, lambda:idle_task(root))`

@metropolis さんの引用の通り、tkinterのバージョンアップで存在しない`__name__`属性を取りに行くことがエラーの原因です。

この回答は別サイトでの類似質問の[ベストアンサー](https://teratail.com/questions/54921#reply-88044)と同一です。
リンク先のコメントも引用します。

> 実際の Python のプログラムでは、コールバックを引数に渡すようなところでは、
>   partial の利用が推奨されてます。例えば、asyncio というモジュールのコールバックの説明では
>   http://docs.python.jp/3.5/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#calls
>
> > 注釈 lambda 関数よりも functools.partial() を使用しましょう。 asyncio はデバッグモードで引数を表示するよう functools.partial() オブジェクトを精査することが出来ますが、lambda 関数の表現は貧弱です。

※server側コードの`syncore.loop()`を`asyncore.loop()`に書き直して動作確認しました。

Comment: どうもありがとございます。lambda関数で、修正したところ、GUIの画面までは、表示されましたが、上記追記箇所（lambda関数を使用した場合のエラーメッセージ）のようなエラーが発生して、server側がダウンしてしまいます。設定のportは、8080なのに、なぜか違うpotrでserverでアクセスしているせいでしょうか？pythonのバージョンも関係あるのでしょうか？

Comment: 少しエラー内容がわかってきました。server側のEchoHandllerクラスのコンストラクタのparentが読み込まれていないのが原因のような気がしました。でも、一体何故なんだろう。client側の設定が必要なのでしょうか？

Comment: もしかして、server側のEchoHandlerクラスのコンストラクタの引数parentってなんだ？定義済みのパラメータ？client側から送られてくるパラメータ？それとも、クラスの外側で、自分で定義しないとダメの？すみませんが、このあたりが、よく分かりませんので、教えてもらえないでしょうか？